# Cannot find module 'react (gulp babelify browerify)

Tags: gulp, browserify, babelify

When I run npm run gulp all worked when creating the javascript. But when I run the javascript inside the browser the following error appears:

_prelude.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'
at o (_prelude.js:1)

I installed react and react-dom, if I use node and require('react') all is fine.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to include the vendors.js in the debug mode.

```
<script src="/static/js/vendors.js"></script>
```

After including all worked fine as expected.